# Selenium says invalid xpath locator

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get value of `HREF` attribute but always it says incorrect Xpath.

Html Code :

[image]

I am trying code :

```
     WebElement Link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'display')]/thead/tbody/tr/td/a"));
     System.out.println(Link.getAttribute("href"));
```

I tried many xpath but none of them worked.

Comment: 1) should it not be: `//table[contains(@class,'display')]/tbody/tr/td/a`?  2) There might be other elements which match that expression, are you sure you've got the right element addressed?   3) Who says _incorrect Xpath_ and how (i.e. any more error details)? 4) Please show use the code, where you try to get value from href attribute.

Comment: Post the HTML please.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters, here is a summary of what they said: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi - I can not. But xpath given from **Würgspaß** worked for me.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow requires that a question includes all the necessary information about a problem as text (i.e. not in images). In this case, your question lacks the HTML source document. If you do not add it, it is likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I have already added HTML code screenshot , is that not enough?

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors for an explanation.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I understand your view but here there is lot of code when I try to get using firebug so I thought that let me take screenshot of necessary part and add to question. I will do take care next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
 WebElement Link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'display')]/tbody/tr/td/a"));
```

Explanation: `tbody` is not nested in `thead`.

Note that a path expression like this can return a set of several nodes, in document order. The `findElement` method only returns the first result node. So: if the `a` element you are looking for is no longer the first one in this table, the path expression breaks.

If the the href is unique, something like this would be less error-prone:

```
 WebElement Link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'display')]//a[@href='/admin/client/product_overrides/edit/242625']"));
```

Comment: How does the first expression depend on the order of rows? As I see it, you meant to say that the first expression depends on the implicit assumption that the first node in the result set will be the wanted one, since `findElement` only returns the first result.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Yes, that's what I meant. If the page code changes and some other `a` element happens to be the first one to appear in the table body, the test might fail. Feel free to edit the answer, to point it out.

Comment: Edited with your permission - and upvoted without your permission :-).